# Oracle query transformation deactivation

Tags: sql, oracle, configuration, transformation

Sometimes I'm going nuts over different query execution plans in development, integration tests, and productive systems. Apart from the usual analysis I run, I just want to know:

Can some of the query optimiser's transformation operations be deactivated on a system level (just as they can be deactivated on a per-query level using hints)?

In this case, I'd expect a `UNION ALL PUSHED PREDICATE` operation for a query looking roughly like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (SELECT ... FROM A
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ... FROM B)
WHERE X = :B1
```

`A` and `B` are views, both selecting from the same tables containing `X`, where `X` is the primary key. It is important that the selection for `X` is pushied into both views `A` and `B` before fetching all of `A` and `B`'s data. And it's also possible, because no complex transformations are required.

So apart from deactivated indexes, bad statistics, bind variable peeking issue, and all the other usual suspects, is there a possibility that the whole Oracle instance just can't do one or two transformations because they're switched off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Various and sundry initialization parameters control query transformation and optimization, and a significant number of them aren't documented.

The following query shows all the undocumented parameters, at least for 10g:

```
SELECT a.ksppinm "Parameter",
       b.ksppstvl "Session Value",
       c.ksppstvl "Instance Value"
  FROM x$ksppi a,
       inner join x$ksppc b
          on a.indx = b.indx
       inner join x$ksppsv c
          on a.indx = c.indx
 WHERE a.ksppinm LIKE '/_%' escape '/'
/
```

Similarly, setting event 10053 will generate an optimization trace file, which will show what parameters (documented or otherwise) affected the generation of the query plan.

Comment: I don't have those views: `select kqftanam from x$kqfta where kqftanam like '%ksppc%'` returns no rows. Have they been changed between 10g and 11g?

Comment: The X$ tables are dark magic - if you can see them, you're likely connected as sysdba, and I've not done enough work on 11g to have gone far down that road.  I recommend the 10053 trace to get how Oracle develops the plan.

Comment: That's what I thought... :) I have some x$ tables but not the ones you mentioned. I tried connecting both as sys or as sysdba. Alright, I'll check the "10053" trace

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have stable execution plans across different instances, you be able to achieve this with exporting statistics on the reference system and importing them into the others.

Examples can be found [in the manual](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/stats.htm#i41854) and [here](http://dbataj.blogspot.com/2007/07/exporting-and-importing-statistics.html)

You might also want to lock the statistics in the target environments after the import so that they are not changed.

Comment: The data differs enormously between those servers (the "less productive" the less data) and is updated on a daily basis (the "less productive" the less often). Accurate and up-to-date statistics are important. So the plan is often different for a good reason. I just want to know if there's the possibility of that "really bad reason" :-)

Comment: @Lukas: I understand that (been there, done that...). But if you want to make sure that a query works fine in the production environment copying the statistics if probably the best you can do.

Comment: @horse: You mean from production to dev, and then develop against those statistics?

Comment: @horse, OK, then I misunderstood you before. We're doing that most of the time and if it's not working I'm running the "usual suspects" tests.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of database initialization parameters that can enable or disable various optimizer options and different query transformations.  So if you have different initialization parameters set in different environments, you can definitely end up in a situation where one environment can do a particular transform and another cannot despite having identical data structures and statistics.

In the case of this particular query, my mind goes immediately to the [`OPTIMIZER_SECURE_VIEW_MERGING`](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2659450800346732572) parameter.  That definitely has the potential to cause problems for this particular type of construct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. I'll review that parameter setting